# Perl STDIN executed before while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop, stdin

I'm a total perl noob and hope this question isn't too stupid!

I'm attempting to write a hangman style game and got it all to work except that for some reason the STDIN seems to execute before the rest of the while loop - so I'm forced to input all of my letter guesses before anything is printed out

```
while()
{
    foreach $letter (@currentword)
    {
        print "$letter";
    }
    print "\n";
    print "Guess a letter: \n";
    chomp($guess = <STDIN>);
    $guess=lc(substr($guess,0,1));  
    if ( $randword =~ /($guess)+/i )
    {
        print "Correct!\n";
        for ($index=0; $index<$wordlength; $index++)
        {
            if ($wordarray[$index] eq $guess)
            {
                $currentword[$index]=$wordarray[$index];
            }
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        print "Incorrect! try again\n";
    }   
    $guesses -= 1;
    last if $guesses < 1;
    $finalword = join("",@currentword);
    last if ($finalword eq $randword);  
}
```

Comment: This code works fine after initializing `$randword`, `$wordlength`, `@wordarray`, `@currentword` and `$guesses` to sensible values.

Comment: Can you show us some more code - specifically where you open STDIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your STDOUT must be attached to something other than a terminal, causing block buffering to be used instead of line buffering. Try adding

```
$| = 1;
```

(I thought reading from STDIN caused STDOUT to be flushed, though.)

Comment: Don't entirely understand what this line does but it works! I'll go do some more reading and find out haha, thanks!

Comment: Turns off buffering for currently selected file handle (STDOUT). See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).